# ¿Por qué es importante dejar las demás carpetas fuera de public_html en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

En caso de que no se entienda correctamente mi pregunta, ya que es más orientada a *cPanel* quisiera aclarar.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Por qué las carpetas **diferentes** de la `carpeta public` deben quedar por fuera del directorio public_html?

Soy nuevo en **Laravel** y me gustaría saber qué problemas de seguridad habría en caso de dejar en la carpeta raíz.

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843345/why-should-i-not-put-my-php-files-in-the-public-html-folder

Comment: Es una medida más de seguridad, de esa forma podes evitar que un usuario intente *"hackear"* el sistema al intentar acceder a los archivos PHP. Cuando los mueves por fuera de  la carpeta *public_html* estos no se puede acceder directamente via *URL*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de pregunta no solo se puede enmarcar en un solo framework, sino en cualquier tipo de proyecto web que pongas a disposición de otros usuarios a traves de un servidor web. El problema está en que la gran mayoría de estos proyectos poseen archivos de configuración donde se establecen particularidades  tales como el servidor de smtp al cual va a conectarse el sistema para enviar los correos, el servidor de base de datos usado para almacenar tu información, la palabra secreta usada por el framework para evitar Ataques Cross Site Forgery Token, todo esto en texto plano. Imagínate que desde la barra de direcciones de tu navegador vayan a la url siguiente: http://www.myhost.com/.env, ya puedes olvidarte de todo tipo de seguridad en tu sistema pues le has dado al atacante todas las llaves de tu casa para que entre y haga lo que quiera. Es por eso que se recomienda solo dar acceso a tu carpeta **public** ya que los usuarios de la web no necesitan ni ver, ni acceder a las demás carpetas, por algo existe ese tipo de estructuras.